# Cannot get publishing status of an Interaction

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, journeybuilder

I'm trying to get the publishing status for a specified `statusId` provided in the response from making a [publishAsync](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/interaction/postPublishInteractionById.html) request but I get the response:

```
<h1>596 Service Not Found</h1>
```

I'm using the route documented for [getPublishStatus](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/interaction/getPublishStatus.html). Is anyone able to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out. The documentation is incorrect. The correct route is:

```
GET /interaction/v1/interactions/publishStatus/{statusId}
```

Note this is different from the documented route:

```
GET /interactions/publishStatus/{statusId}
```

If someone could update the documentation, I think that would be a good idea.

Comment: They are misleading maybe, but not incorrect. The routes assume you know the service and version. The code samples are accurate.

Comment: Hello Kelly, you are of course correct. Had I taken the time to read the documentation, then I would have observed that the route is correctly provided in the sample payload request. Sorry about that.

Comment: No worries. We are evaluating how to make it more clear.